# Including an integer in a print statement

Tags: python

I am trying this, where `i` is an integer:

```
sys.stdout.write('\thello world %d.\n' % i+1)
```

and it says "cannot concatenate str and int". I have tried various combinations:

```
int(i) + 1
i + int(1)
```

... but it's not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sys.stdout.write('\thello world %d.\n' % (i+1))
```

Mind the brackets.

(The `%` operator binds more tightly than the `+` operator, so you wind up trying to add 1 to the formatted string, which is an error.)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
sys.stdout.write('\thello world %d.\n' % (i+1))
```

Python interpret your way as ('...' % i) + 1

Answer (score 1):

`str.format` is preferred if your Python version is new enough to support it (Python2.6+)<sup>†</sup> see that you don't even need to worry about the precedence of `%` and `+` here.

```
sys.stdout.write('\thello world {}.\n'.format(i+1))
```

or as the title of the question suggests - using a print statement

```
print '\thello world {}.'.format(i+1)
```

In Python3, `print` is a function, so you need to call it like this

```
print('\thello world {}.'.format(i+1))
```

---

† In Python2.6 you need to use `{0}` in stead of plain `{}`